# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" Unable to show OrderScreen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

This is the first time I'm asking a question on stackoverflow, please don't mind if something is not right

Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order"
The order details is not being fetched

**OrderScreen.js**

```
const OrderScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const { orderId } = useParams()

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails)
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId))
  }, [orderId, dispatch])

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : error ? (
    <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
  ) : (
    <>
      <h1>Order</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Shipping</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Address: </strong>
                {order.shippingAddress.address}, {order.shippingAddress.city},
                {order.shippingAddress.postalCode},{' '}
                {order.shippingAddress.country}
              </p>
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Payment Method</h2>
              <strong>Method: </strong>
              {order.paymentMethod}
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Order Items</h2>
              {order.orderItems.length === 0 ? (
                <Message>Order is empty</Message>
              ) : (
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                  {order.orderItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col md={1}>
                          <Image
                            src={item.image}
                            alt={item.name}
                            fluid
                            rounded
                          />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                          <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>
                            {item.name}
                          </Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                          {item.qty} x AED {item.price} = AED{' '}
                          {item.qty * item.price}
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  ))}
                </ListGroup>
              )}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Items</Col>
                  <Col>AED {order.itemsPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Shipping</Col>
                  <Col>AED {order.shippingPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Tax</Col>
                  <Col>AED {order.taxPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Total</Col>
                  <Col>AED {order.totalPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}
```

**getOrderDetails function from orderActions.js**

```
export const getOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    })

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    }

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${id}`, config)

    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message

    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    })
  }
}
```

**getOrderById function from orderController.js
**

```
const getOrderById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  //fetch order
  const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate(
    'user',
    'name email'
  )

  if (order) {
    res.json(order)
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Order not found')
  }
})
```

**
orderSchema from orderModel.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paymentResult: {
      id: { type: String },
      status: { type: String },
      update_time: { type: String },
      email_address: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    shippingPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)

export default Order
```

and the below mentioned error message is returned as payload.

When I click placeorder button I want to show orderScreen and fetch all the data mentioned in orderScreen

Comment: Try logging the value of req.params